# zlib inflate giving data error in erlang

Tags: erlang, zlib

I have a java client which is sending some message to an erlang server process listening on TCP.The java client sends the data using outputstream.On the server side i am using following call to uncompress the data after initialising zlib

```
zlib:inflate(ZStream, Data),
```

where Data is binary.I am getting data_error on this call.
Under what conditions do I get data_error with zlib.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a 0 or -15 WindowBits, would help if you paste more code like the zlib:inflateInit call, the binary dump of Data variable, and the Java side zlib init.

Answer (score -1):

If you are streaming the data in relatively small chunks, you can use my [ezlib on Github](https://github.com/silviucpp/ezlib).

Performance wise it's around 69 % faster than erlang driver and also works better when you have concurrent sessions.

To integrate, use rebar as you would do for any other erlang app. To run a small example:

```
StringBin = <<"this is a string compressed with zlib nif library">>,
{ok, DeflateRef} = ezlib:new(?Z_DEFLATE),
{ok, InflateRef} = ezlib:new(?Z_INFLATE),
CompressedBin = ezlib:process(DeflateRef, StringBin),
DecompressedBin = ezlib:process(InflateRef, CompressedBin).
```

Do not use it to compress large blocks, because you can block the erlang scheduler. I will change this in the subsequent versions.

Comment: Just linking to your own stuff is [not a good answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). A good answer that involves an off-site resource includes the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and references the following: _What is this thing you're talking about? Where do I install it? How do I install it? How do I use this thing to solve the **exact problem** I have in my question? Are you affiliated with this thing in any way, shape, or form?_ See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022)

Comment: @Mogsdad feel free to delete my post . I don't get any benefits if peoples are using or not my library . I created that library because erlang zlib driver it' pretty bad. You can google it and you will find a lot of complains for the fact that's not working properly with concurrent processes. For this fact probably also other companies created their own libraries (for example p1 into their ejabberd project) : https://github.com/processone/zlib

Comment: Hi Silviu - thanks for responding. I'm just another user - I can't delete your post, and that's not what my comment was about. I'm saying you could make your answer better with a bit more information.

Comment: @silviu  Link-only answers are not the way of SO. Links may be outdated someday. Put essential informations in your answer!

Comment: @Odebra if the linked page is not longer exist also project will not longer exist so the entire response will be useless. You will have the lines of code that integrates but you wont be available to do this.